# Symfony 4 Web Assets

Tags: symfony

I'm using symfony 4 and I'm trying to use web-encore. I have several css and js files share for all the webste.

I tried to use .createSharedEntry in my webpack.config.js :

```
.createSharedEntry('vendor', [
    'assets/css/bootrap.min.css',
    'assets/css/custom.scss',
    'assets/css/components.scss',
    'assets/css/core.scss',
    'assets/css/global.scss',

    'assets/js/bootsrap.min.js',
    'assets/js/jquery.easing.js',
    'assets/js/jquery.min.js',
    'assets/js/jquery-migrate.min.js',
    'assets/js/popper.min.js'
])
```

When I lauch the command yarn run encore dev

I have somme errors :  ERROR  Failed to compile with 10 errors                                                                                   05:00:35

These dependencies were not found:

I don't what I have done wrong

Best regards

Comment: have you run `php app/console assets:install` before?

Comment: no I will try thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you use createSharedEntry but you could use the following for webpack.config.js:

```
.addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
```

And the file app.js itself:

```
require('./css/bootrap.min.css');
require('./css/custom.scss');
...

// Jquery
const $ = require('jquery');
global.$ = $;
global.jQuery = $;

// Add node_module JS
require('./js/bootsrap.min.js');
require('./js/jquery.easing.js');
...
```

After this i use "yarn run encore dev" or an npm equivalent

Fot the template you can then use:

CSS:

```
    {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
```

JS:

```
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
```

This is similiar to the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html)